# Unable to read json object from jquery ajax() request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've been browsing SO for a few now and can't find an answer that works for me, anyway, here's the JS:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url:'scripts/form.php?'+
        'name='+$('#name').val()+
        '&comment='+$('#comment').val(),
    type:'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    complete:function(success) { 
        alert(success.responseText);
        alert(success.name);
    }
});
```

Here's the (summarized) script being

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
$name    = $_GET['name'];
$comment = $_GET['comment'];

echo json_encode(array('name'=>$name, 'comment'=>$comment));
```

Here's the output from the alert boxes:

1. {"name":"test name","comment":"test comment"}
2. undefined

I've tried a bunch of different things, but I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the `success` event instead of the `complete` event -- otherwise, the response does not get parsed as JSON automatically.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url:'scripts/form.php?'+
        'name='+$('#name').val()+
        '&comment='+$('#comment').val(),
    type:'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(data) { 
        alert(data.name);
    }
});
```

If you want to use the `complete` handler, you will need to parse the return value with [`$.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) before being able to use it as an object:

```
var response = $.parseJSON(success.responseText);
```

Comment: Don't know why I fought this for a day before asking SO.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't see a reason to `POST` the request here - the data's in the URL parameters anyway.

Comment: @Matt: It was a 'hail Mary' attempt at getting the response to work how I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) since you don't need to full flexibility of `$.ajax()`.

```
$.getJSON('scripts/form.php',
{
    name: $('#name').val(),
    comment: $('#comment').val()
}, function (data)
{
    alert(data.name);
});
```